# Will instance of child pages/view models be disposed of if I move back to root page by calling GoToAsync()?

Tags: maui

I have 3 pages in my MAUI app.

```
Page 1 
  Page 2
    Page 3
```

I can navigate from page1 -> page2 -> page3. When navigating, page 2 and 3 are added to navigation stack.

```
await MauiShell.Current.GoToAsync(Routes.Page2);
```

If I call `GoToAsync("//Page1")` in page 3 to go back to page1, will the instance of page 2 and 3 be diposed of automatically? or will they live forever (= memory leak) unless I somehow manually dispose of them?

`PopToRootAsync()` seems to be a better way to go back to page1 as it is the root of the navigation stack, but I need to pass some values back to page 1 and I don't see built-in mechanism to do so using `PopToRootAsync()`.

---

**More Details:**

Page 1 is registered as a root of the `Tab` and the others are registered as sub pages like this:

AppShell.xaml

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Test Items" Icon="icon.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Page1}" Route="{x:Static routing:Routes.Page1}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(Routes.Page2, typeof(Page2));
Routing.RegisterRoute(Routes.Page3, typeof(Page3));
```

Page 2, 3 and their view models are instantiated (injected) as transient. I set a breakpoint in the constructor of page2's and 3's view model and it stops there every time I navigate to page 2 and 3.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you can pass information from anywhere to anywhere else via publish-subscribe, using [Community Toolkit - Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger).

Answer (score 1):

If you register your **Page** and **ViewModel** as `Singleton` with dependency injection, they will be kept in state and memory which can be used throughout the lifetime. For more information, you can refer to [my previous answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75946829/9644964).

Additionally, as Steve suggested, you can use `WeakReferenceMessenger` in the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) NuGet package to send and receive messages between different objects. For more information, please refer this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger

Hopefully this clears that up a little bit.